# How to translate a script to Zend Framework?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I have this situation:

```
<select name="year" >
    <?php 
        $today = date("Y"); 
        for ($i=2005; $i<=$today; $i++){
            echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

This will give me the years `2005` through `2011, ...`

in zend framework a drop down will look like this:

```
$this->addElement('select', 'department', array(
    'label'        => 'Year:',
    'multiOptions' => array('A' => 'A', 'B' => 'B', 'C' => 'C',),
    'value'        => @$val->_listing_type_id
));
```

How can I translate my `for loop` script to create the years in the Zend Framework script? I know I can use the first script in Zend Framework but I want to keep the syntax consistent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `range` to create an array of numbers from 2005 to 2011:

```
...
'multiOptions' => range(2005, 2011),
...
```

If Zend really does expect an array where the keys/values must be the same, you can use `array_combine` to produce the required array:

```
'multiOptions' => array_combine(range(2005, 2011), range(2005, 2011))
```

This will produce `array(2005 => 2005, 2006 => 2006, ..., 2011 => 2011)`.

Comment: thanks both of you, both solutions work, though this one is faster for what i need now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to modify elements if you have a reference to them.

```
$department = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('department');
$department->setLabel('Year:');
.....
$this->addElement($department);
```

Then you can modify the multiOptions array as needed:

```
 $today = date("Y"); 
 for ($i=2005; $i<=$today; $i++){
   $department->addMultiOption($i, $i);
 }
```